# How to allow users in Cloud Identity to access Google Drive and other services in Google

Tags: google-cloud-identity

I administrate users in Cloud Identity Free Edition now.
They can't use Google Drive, Colaboratory, Spread Sheet, and so on after they started being controlled in Cloud Identity.
What should I do to allow them to use those services again with controlling them?
Should I switch Free Edition to Premium Edition or GSuite?

Answer (score 1):

Correction to my answer earlier to this topic.

Google Drive is actually present in Cloud Identity Free and Premium Edition.
It is just limited to 15GB per User. Just have a look at the [Cloud Identity Core Services](https://cloud.google.com/terms/identity/user-features.html)

You have to activate it in the Admin Console (https://admin.google.com), and after that it is available for all users in the domain, Organizational Unit or group, that you have chosen to activate it for.

If you need additional configuration options to control the access to drive and the sharing possibilities in your domain, you should however switch to a G Suite Licence

Comment: Cloud Identity Free plans for Workspace include zero storage quota -- you have to upgrade to have access to storage. Note that this was a change from the prior G Suite plan, which gives you 15GB with the Cloud Identity Free plan. Times are changing.